# Writing function to convert given name into camelCase

Tags: javascript, replace

It works for some name but doesn’t work for `lastName` that starts with capital letters.

```js
const toCamelCase = function(firstName, lastName) {
  console.log(firstName.toLowerCase() + lastName.toLowerCase().replace(lastName[0], lastName[0].toUpperCase()));
};

toCamelCase('albert', 'einstein');
toCamelCase('MR', 'beast');
toCamelCase('john', 'SMITH');
```

Comment: `lastName.toLowerCase()` is `"smith"`. `lastName[0]` is `"S"`. There is no `"S"` in `"smith"`.

Comment: Albert Einstein, Mr. Beast, and John Smith walk into a bar. The bartender asks, "What year is it?!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save `lastName.toLowerCase()` first it will solve your problem.

```js
const toCamelCase = function (firstName, lastName) {
  const convertedLastName = lastName.toLowerCase();
  console.log(
    firstName.toLowerCase() +
      convertedLastName.replace(convertedLastName[0], convertedLastName[0].toUpperCase())
  );
};
toCamelCase('albert', 'einstein'); 
toCamelCase('MR', 'beast');
toCamelCase('john', 'SMITH');
```

Comment: It should be enough to add .toLowerCase() also inside the replace, this way you don't need a new variable

Comment: @PatrickVisi thank you for the feedback, I guess it's a trade-off between calling a function twice versus making a new variable. I'm not sure which is better, what do you think?

Edit: Also, I feel it is more readable this way.

Comment: At this point probably doesn't matter that much.
Your solution I would say is more readable, and if the function took a lot of time/resources to run then yours is definitely better

I added the comment since the question wanted to solve it in 1 line and this is how would you do it in 1 line

Comment: @PatrickVisi Noted, thank you. I'm quite against one line solutions if it's not readable or too long.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74912170/writing-function-to-convert-given-name-into-camelcase#comment132200599_74912184) "_I'm not sure which is better, what do you think?_": @Ben [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try doing it this way:

```
export const toCamelCase = (firstName, lastName) => {
    return `${firstName.toLowerCase()}${lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${lastName.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`;
};
```